# PdfFileWriter doesn't work because of content including Chineses character

Tags: python, pypdf

I was trying to create a code to generate a combined pdf from a bunch of small pdf files while I found the script failing with UnicodeEncodeError error.

I also tried to include encoding param by
with open("Combined.pdf", "w",encoding='utf-8-sig') as outputStream:
but compiler said it needs to be binary 'wb' mode. So this isn't working.
Below is the code:

```
writer = PdfFileWriter()

input_stream = []
for f2 in f_re:
    inputf_file = str(mypath+'\\'+f2[2])
    input_stream.append(open(inputf_file,'rb'))


for reader in map(PdfFileReader, input_stream):
    for n in range(reader.getNumPages()):
        writer.addPage(reader.getPage(n))
with open("Combined.pdf", "wb") as outputStream:
    writer.write(outputStream)
    writer.save()

for f in input_stream:
    f.close()
```

Below is error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Workspace\Python\py_CombinPDF\py_combinePDF.py", line 89, in <module>
    writer.write(outputStream)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 501, in write
    obj.writeToStream(stream, key)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 549, in writeToStream
    value.writeToStream(stream, encryption_key)
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py", line 472, in writeToStream
    stream.write(b_(self))
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\utils.py", line 238, in b_
    r = s.encode('latin-1')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 8-9: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Comment: Hi! This question has been solved by go to PyPDF2\utils.py, just in the line238 error message indicates, I change the original code 
r = s.encode('latin-1') to
r = s.encode('utf-8')
and the problem was solved, I'm going to close this question.
Hope it helps others as well!

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading PyPDF2 solved this issue.

Now, 4 years later, people should use `pypdf`. It contains the latest code (I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2 and pypdf)